# Python: Access members of a function from outside that function

Tags: python, scope

Say I had two functions, one belonging to another like so.

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        print("im bar")
    print("im foo and can call bar")
print("i can call foo, but not bar?")
```

How would refer to or call bar?
Would I do `foo.bar()`?

If `bar` were not a function like if `bar = 1` then how would I access that?

I'm aware I could move `bar` out of `foo` but is there any other way?

Comment: `bar` is not a member of `foo`. It is a local variable. To access the value outside you must return the value

Comment: `bar` only exists while `foo` is executing. As soon as `foo` ends, `bar` goes out of scope and ceases to exist. And that's just the first conceptual problem…

Comment: it sounds like this should be in a class with a staticmethod

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do what you want to do here, i.e. calling `foo.bar` and expect to get the result. You can, however, turn `foo` into a class and then try it that way.